# GCM Notifications in my app overlaps the older and displays the newest one.

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Hi friends I have created an android project using GCM messaging. I am able to send and receive the notifications perfectly. But the problem arises when ever I send more than one notification. The second notification always overlaps the first one. To be precise - Suppose I have sent 3 notifications in a day, and meanwhile a user of my app was offline as soon as he comes online he will receive all notifications but will be able to see only the last one. That is the notification tone will be playing three times but only the last notification will be visible. Instead I would like to see all the three notifications one after the other. How to resolve this problem please help me. 
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking something like this:
[Notification inbox style however gets updated when a notification comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285136/notification-inbox-style-however-gets-updated-when-a-notification-comes)

you need to use inboxStyle to achieve this.

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder()
     .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
         .addLine(str1)
         .addLine(str2)
         .setContentTitle("")
         .setSummaryText("+3 more"))
     .build();
```

this is right from the official website 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html

and this is the entire tutorial
https://priyankacool10.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/how-to-create-notifications-in-android/

If the answer serves your purpose don't forget to accept the answer :)